# Is it possible to use sendfile() to copy directories

Tags: c, linux, sendfile

I'm trying to use `sendfile()` to implement a copy program.

However it failed when I was trying to copy directories. Isn't directory a special file type in Linux?

Here is the code I'm using now. It's copied from another answer from StackOverflow.

```
int copy_file(const char *to, const char *from) {
    int read_fd; int write_fd;
    struct stat stat_buf;
    off_t offset = 0;
    /* Open the input file. */
    read_fd = open(from, O_RDONLY);
    /* Stat the input file to obtain its size. */
    fstat (read_fd, &stat_buf);
    /* Open the output file for writing, with the same permissions as the source file. */
    write_fd = open(to, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, stat_buf.st_mode);
    /* Blast the bytes from one file to the other. */
    int err = sendfile(write_fd, read_fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
    /* Close up. */
    close (read_fd);
    close (write_fd);
    return err;
}
```

**Appending**

The return value I got is -1. And I got a **file**, not directory, that have `to` path.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit.

The output of `uname -r` is `3.11.0-20-generic`.

Comment: It failed where ? You do not check any return value ! What is the error you get ? What kernel version is it ?

Comment: Maybe one of your open calls failed or both. Also check errno variable. http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile

Comment: @Malkocoglu Already checked, errno is not set. I think tripleee's explanation makes sense enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot transmit a directory like this. While technically it is true that a directory is a kind of file on some Unices, its contents are not portable to another file system, or even another directory in the same file system. For this and other reasons, the system won't allow you to treat a directory as just another file.

Comment: Got it. But this is not documented in the `sendfile()` man page. So I guess, I'll just use `mkdir()` to copy directories.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation of the copy command in linux. Please follow this.

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/143382-implementation-linux-cp-copy-command-c-language.html

Comment: Yah... I've already done some google works, and had this looked. It's not what I want. I want to use `sendfile()`.